# Is there a way to show drop down in react leaflet on the map

Tags: reactjs, react-leaflet

I am trying to show a simple dropdown on the react leaflet map to show markers of certain data. Once the user chooses an option from drop down i want some data to display on the map. Currently i have not found a straight forward way to do it. Or any example code online.

I have tried a module react-leaflet-control but i can't get it to work I am assuming because of some typescript errors. I have tried to show check boxes instead of a drop down using react-leaflet `LayerControl.Overlay` but i don't think that is what i need and it's not really usable for my case. Any suggestions and example code will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried `LayersControl`? You can find some documentation [here](https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/en/components.html#layerscontrol)

This is how it works. You define a `LayersControl` tag, and can add the `Overlay` tag with your GeoJSON data. Each `Overlay` tag will be a different layer. So you can have multiples GeoJSON layers. Each layer will be one item on the dropdown.

```
<LayersControl position="topright" collapsed={false}>
    {this.state.layersName.map((layerName, i) => {
        return (
            <Overlay key={i} name={`${layerName}`} checked>
                <GeoJSON
                    data={this.state.layersData[i]}
                />
            </Overlay>
        )
    })}
</LayersControl>
```

[image]